# Turtle shapes don't fill whole screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

When I run this code the shapes only appear in a very small area and not the whole turtle screen, and I was wondering, why?  I also need to be able to call `shape_3`, so I have to leave all the imports under a `def`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
def shape_3():
    import random
    import turtle
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    alex = turtle.Turtle()
    alex.speed(10000)
    alex.ht()
def rectangle(turtle):
    import random
    import turtle
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    alex = turtle.Turtle()
    alex.speed(10000)
    alex.ht()
    w = random.randint(10,45)
    h = random.randint(10,45)
    color = random.randint(0,2)
    if color == 0:
        alex.fillcolor("aqua")
        alex.color("aqua")
    else:
        alex.fillcolor("white")
        alex.color("white")
    alex.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        alex.forward(h)
        alex.right(90)
        alex.forward(w)
        alex.right(90)
    alex.end_fill()
def random_rect():
    import random
    import turtle
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    alex = turtle.Turtle()
    alex.speed(10000)
    alex.ht()
    for i in range(300):
        x = random.randint(-480,480)
        y = random.randint(-405,405)
        alex.penup()
        alex.goto(x,y)
        alex.pendown()
        rectangle(alex)
print(shape_3(random_rect()))
```

Comment: *I also need to be able to call shape_3 so i have to leave all the imports under a def.* Why can't you call shape_3 if you move all your imports at the start of the file?

Comment: I tried that but it only creates the shape in a very small area and i dont know why it does that @Xis88

Answer (score 0):

Move everything from `shape3` to the start of the file. I don't see any benefit of your design besides redundancy and confusion.

Add spaces after methods.

Use `random.choice` to choose color.

**You don't use turtle in your rectangle(turtle) method.** Use it.

```
import random
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
alex = turtle.Turtle()
alex.speed(10000)
alex.ht()

def rectangle(turtle):
    w = random.randint(10,45)
    h = random.randint(10,45)
    color = random.choice("aqua", "white")
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        turtle.forward(h)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(w)
        turtle.right(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

def random_rect():
    for i in range(300):
        x = random.randint(-480,480)
        y = random.randint(-405,405)
        alex.penup()
        alex.goto(x,y)
        alex.pendown()
        rectangle(alex)
```

Fixing all these should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main cause of your problems is that you're not passing and using the `turtle` argument passed the `rectangle()` function properly — it's also why you think you have to `import` the modules in every function.

In your code the argument passed to `rectangle()` is named `turtle` which conflicts with the name of the same module. You then immediately `import turtle` which replaces the argument's value with that of the module. I've changed the argument's name to `a_turtle` to prevent this (and better describe what it is). This allows the two modules to just be `import`ed once at the beginning of the script.

I also elminated the `shape_3()` function which does nothing useful and just call `random_rect()` directly (besides that, `shape_3()` didn't take an argument anyway).

```
import random
import turtle

def rectangle(a_turtle):
    w = random.randint(10,45)
    h = random.randint(10,45)
    color = random.randint(0,2)
    if color == 0:
        a_turtle.fillcolor("aqua")
        a_turtle.color("aqua")
    else:
        a_turtle.fillcolor("white")
        a_turtle.color("white")
    a_turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        a_turtle.forward(h)
        a_turtle.right(90)
        a_turtle.forward(w)
        a_turtle.right(90)
    a_turtle.end_fill()

def random_rect():
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    alex = turtle.Turtle()
    alex.speed(10000)
    alex.ht()
    for i in range(300):
        x = random.randint(-480,480)
        y = random.randint(-405,405)
        alex.penup()
        alex.goto(x,y)
        alex.pendown()
        rectangle(alex)

random_rect()
```